# Does NSCoding automatically instantiate the correct derived class

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I want: A number of derived classes inheriting from a base which conforms to `NSCoding`.

When I'm decoding, do I need to "do something" to take care of instantiating the correct derived class, or does `NSCoding` handle all that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do something for NSCoding to instantiate the correct sub class for you. It does this automatically.

If your base class needs to encode or decode itself, don't forget you need to call super in your implementations:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
  [super encodeWithCoder:coder];

  // And do your own encoding.
}
```

and

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  if(self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder]) 
  {
    // Do your own decoding here.
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: :-) Is that a "yes", or a "no"?

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite or add some extra properties to store in the archiver, NSCoding does it all for you

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll submit an edit to summarise that, or would you prefer to?